# Deploy nodejs application to dedicated server with Github Actions

Tags: github, nestjs, continuous-deployment, github-actions, dedicated-server

I have a simple question, but I can't find the answer. I've searched everywhere (exaggeration).

**Description**

I have dedicated server running ubuntu where my nestjs application is running. I am using github for my remote repository and my current deployment process is:

1. `local: git push` push changes to github repository
2. `local: ssh user@IP` access my server via SSH
3. `server: git pull` pull changes to server from github repository
4. `server: npm run build` build project
5. `server: pm2 restart myapp` restart application

Manual process that take some amount of time.

**Question**

Can I use Github Actions to automate this process and how? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

yes you can do this. I have already written a guide for the exact thing that you are looking for. check it out.

https://chathula.dev/how-to-set-up-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-a-node-js-app-with-github-actions/